# How to add HTTP security headers to Next.js app

Tags: http-headers, next.js

I am completely new in web development and I'm trying to add HTTP security headers to my Next.js app but if I check it in securityheader.com it doesn't seem to work.

```
const express = require("express");
const next = require("next");
const helmet = require("helmet");

const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production";
const app = next({ dev });
const handle = app.getRequestHandler();

app
  .prepare()
  .then(() => {
    const server = express();
    server.use(helmet());
    server.use(helmet.xframe());
    server.use(helmet.hsts());

    server.get("*", (req, res) => {
      return handle(req, res);
    });

    server.listen(3000, err => {
      if (err) throw err;
      console.log("> Ready on http://localhost:3000");
    });
  })
  .catch(ex => {
    console.error(ex.stack);
    process.exit(1);
  });
```

I'm looking for information for 4 days already and I still didn't find any example how to do it and I can't figure it out what exactly I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Which security headers? You need to elaborate more

Comment: I need to add at least these: Strict-Transport-Security, Content-Security-Policy, X-Frame-Options, X-Content-Type-Options, Referrer-Policy, Feature-Policy.

Comment: The code that I've posted I have in **ssr-server.js** file in the root of my project. I'm not sure if it supposes to be there or maybe in some another file.

Answer (score 2):

I found 2 solutions:

1. You can use Jaga Apple's `next-secure-headers` npm package which can be found [here](https://github.com/jagaapple/next-secure-headers) on GitHub. This is basically a TypeScript-based wrapper that can be used on the whole `App` component or on individual `Page` components, by accessing a request object during the Next.js `getInitialProps` lifecycle, which unfortunately also forms this [issue](https://github.com/jagaapple/next-secure-headers/issues/11). You will also need to know a little bit of TypeScript to use it, as well as having to install TypeScript according to these Next.js [instructions](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/typescript), or this Next.js [tutorial](https://nextjs.org/learn/excel/typescript).
2. The above solution, however, currently does not work if you are deploying your [Next.js](https://nextjs.org/) project to [Vercel](http://vercel.com) (which used to be Zeit/Now), which is what I personally prefer since Next.js was created for Vercel. The solution I found for this case was to implement a custom [routes/headers](https://vercel.com/docs/configuration#routes/headers) configuration in `now.json`, for example:

```
{
  ..., // <-- Other configuration options
  "routes": [
    {
      "src": "/.*",
      "headers": {
        "Content-Security-Policy": "default-src 'self'; img-src 'self' https://cdn.sanity.io; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'",
        "Feature-Policy": "'none'",
        "Referrer-Policy": "same-origin",
        "X-Content-Type-Options": "nosniff",
        "X-Frame-Options": "deny",
        "X-XSS-Protection": "1"
      },
      "continue": true
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Content-Security-Policy` is not enabled by default in [helmet](https://www.npmjs.com/package/helmet), to enable it use

```js
server.use(helmet.contentSecurityPolicy({
  directives: {
    defaultSrc: ["'self'"],
    styleSrc: ["'self'", 'maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com']
  }
}))
```

to enable X-Frame-Options

```
server.use(frameguard({
  action: 'allow-from',
  domain: 'http://example.com'
}))
```

For more info, check [lib docs](https://helmetjs.github.io/docs/)